# Å in form option

Tags: forms

I have

```
$form['type'] = array(
'#title' => t('Country'),
'#type' => 'select',
'#name' => 'countrye',      
'#id' => 'country',
'#options' => array(
                    'Afghanistan' => t('Afghanistan'),
                    'Åland Islands' => t('&Aring;land Islands'),
                    'Albania' => t('Albania'),
```

etc

But `'Åland Islands' => t('Åland Islands')`, is coming out blank as it does like Å. How you you get Å to be recognised please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [html_entity_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) function:

> html_entity_decode — Convert all HTML entities to their applicable characters

```
echo html_entity_decode('&Aring;land Islands');
```

Output:

> Åland Islands

In your code:

```
$form['type'] = array(
'#title' => t('Country'),
'#type' => 'select',
'#name' => 'countrye',      
'#id' => 'country',
'#options' => array(
                    'Afghanistan' => t('Afghanistan'),
                    'Åland Islands' => t(html_entity_decode('&Aring;land Islands')),
                    'Albania' => t('Albania'),
```

Comment: @PamelaWhittaker in this case you can check the answer as accepted, if you don't know how, read this http://drupal.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: oops sorry I didn't see the tick mark. I had looked for a button and didn't see one

Comment: @PamelaWhittaker don't worry, it's just for a reference to another users to show them the correct answer ;-), good luck in yor project